# Initialize table with enumerated data

Tags: sql-server, while-loop

I'd like to initialize a table with enumerated data like

```
| x | y | z | domain | 
|---|---|---|--------|
| 1 | 1 | 1 | a.com  | 
| 1 | 2 | 1 | a.com  | 
| 1 | 3 | 1 | a.com  |
```

By running a stored procedure like:

```
exec init_table 10, 10, 1
```

Some table looks like

```
| i | domain | 
|---|--------|
| 1 | a.com  |
| 2 | b.com  |
```

I have the following...

```
-- Set z to default if `null` is passed in
if (@num_coordinate_z is null) begin set @num_coordinate_z = 1 end

-- Initialize counters for loop
declare @x int = 1, @y int = 1, @z int = 1, @d int = 1
declare @num_domains int = (select distinct count(domain) from 
someDb..someTable)

while (@x <= @num_coordinate_x) begin
  while (@y <= @num_coordinate_y) begin
    while (@z <= @num_coordinate_z) begin
      while (@d <= @num_domains)      begin

        insert into configMotorsTest (
          coordinate_x,
          coordinate_y,
          coordinate_z,
          domain
        ) values (
          @x,
          @y,
          @z,
          (select [domain] from someDb..someTable where [i] = @d)
        )

        set @d = @d + 1

      end 
      set @x = @x + 1
     end
     set @y = @y + 1
   end
   set @z = @z + 1
 end
```

But it is only writing one record.

How would I initialize a (10, 10, 1, 2) (x, y, z, domain) table with a stored procedure `exec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far better suited with a tally. A `WHILE` loop is by far the worst way to do this. It's awfully slow.

Assuming you have a table of domain addresses, then you could simply do something like:

```
WITH Tally AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))N(N))
SELECT N1.N AS x,
       N2.N AS y,
       N3.N AS z,
       D.Domain
FROM dbo.DomainTable D
     CROSS JOIN N N1
     CROSS JOIN N N2
     CROSS JOIN N N3;
```

This'll create 1000 (10*10*10) rows for each email address, with ever variation of `x`, `y`, and `z`.

For a more "dynamic" approach:

```
DECLARE @x int = 10,
        @y int = 10,
        @z int = 1;

DECLARE @m int = (SELECT MAX(V.N) FROM (VALUES(@x),(@y),(@z))V(N));

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@m)
           ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --this'll create 10,000 rows
SELECT T1.I AS x,
       T2.I AS y,
       T3.I AS z,
       D.Domain
FROM dbo.DomainTable D
     CROSS JOIN Tally T1
     CROSS JOIN Tally T2
     CROSS JOIN Tally T3
WHERE T1.I <= @x
  AND T2.I <= @y
  AND T3.I <= @z;
```

If `@x`, `@y` and `@z` had a value of `1000` then this would create 1000^3 (1,000,000,000) rows, and it accepts a value up to 10,000.

I do not, however, for one second recommend that you really do try to create over 1million rows in a single go; that'll just fill your transaction log and likely result in a failure.

Comment: It looks like the from is not dynamic. I'd like to run an `exec` command with custom numbers....

Comment: What is the maximum value for `x`, `y`, or `z`, @Matthew?

Comment: 100,000,000 would be a decent number. But... the array size isn't necessarily symmetric. It could be (10, 6, 1) for example...

Comment: 100,000,000? Seriously? That would mean you could have a *potention* 100,000,000^3 rows, which is 1x10^27!!!

Comment: Updated the answer for you, @Matthew.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was hoping to use a dynamic while loop to make debugging simpler... The optimal case is ~100 rows and will be about run once per week.

Comment: A dynamic `WHILE` would by far be the slowest way to do this, @Matthew . SQL isn't a Programming language, it's a Query Language. It works in sets. This is exactly what the above does and it's far more efficient.

Comment: I hear you... I like it, but how do I insert the select into a table?

Comment: USe an `INSERT` statement, @Matthew .

Comment: Awesome. There is an extra `)` on line 13 that it won't let me edit. Thank you for your help :).

Comment: I should really turn off the autocomplete feature on ADS. Glad to have helped, @Matthew .